# Tablet format for Ubuntu Touch Emulator (ETA)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, emulation

Does anyone have any idea how long we are likely to be waiting for the tablet format to be released for the Ubuntu Touch Emulator?  From what I can see so far the emulator only emulates a phone.  I have found suggestions that the tablet format is being or is planned to be developed but can't find details on when it is hoped this will be available.  (I realise that any date will be approximate and probably be pushed back but some idea would be helpful.  Even better would be a page where I could follow the progress of the project.)